# R sf st_write error: feature not successfully written

Tags: r, r-sf

I am saving a shapefile which looks like below:

```
Simple feature collection with 337152 features and 35 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -137.9625 ymin: 5.495833 xmax: -52.61605 ymax: 62.74232
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

st_write(sf_dat, 'temp.shp'))
```

I get 50 warnings which says:

```
Warning messages:
1: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  ... :
  GDAL Message 1: Value 7120014530 of field hybas_id of feature 0 not successfully written. 
Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width
```

I am not able to understand the error. Could anyone explain why this is happening?
Thank you

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure but it seems like your value is too large for the field types implemented in the shapefile format (c.f. [ESRI: ArcGIS field data types](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm#GUID-70728949-2016-4DB5-A723-5493B4330AE0)): Long integer seem to offer a resolution of 32-bit covering a range between -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647.

Comment: In addition to falk-env's input I encourage you to check the saved dataset and find this row. Normally when I get this warning the value is still there. See solution for two possible workarounds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try saving it to a geopackage, temp.gpkg, turn your back away from shapefiles and never look back.

```
st_write(sf_dat, 'temp.gpkg'))
```

Comment: Reasonable indeed! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of this problem, I would suggest trying [I havent ran the code so there proceed with caution]:

- Saving in a different format e.g. geojson using `st_write(sf_dat, 'temp.geojson'))`
- Re-formatting the fied to a string before saving it, to then format it back to integer when loading the dataset:

```
sf_dat$hybas_id <- as.character(sf_dat$hybas_id)
st_write(sf_dat, 'temp.shp')) 

## then to re-load data (also using the dplyr library):
sf_dat <- st_read('temp.shp') %>% mutate(hybas_id  = as.integer(hybas_id)))
```

**EDIT:** the advice provided by @Spacedman is great because it removes the need for handling data classes with every write / read - which can turn very tricky when sharing data with others. See comment for more.

Comment: Alternatively, and this is quite common when working with shapefiles, you could also think about dropping some accuracy and saving the value in thousands, e.g. `newval_1000 <- 7120015` instead of `val <- 7120014530`. But this depends on your use case, of course.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I will try to work with this.

Comment: The option suggested by @falk-env is good, but beware - if the hybas_id field is supposed to be a unique identifier, then you would lose it. In that case, saving as a string might be better, or saving as a float with all the decimals to then multiply by 1000 upon re-read.

Comment: Yup, when `hybas_id` is your unique identifier, make sure to save your value as character. Shapefile allow storage up to 254 characters per field if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Numerics for unique identifiers are always a fail. Give them a character prefix so that the have to be character and make life harder for people who might do dumb things like subtract one ID from another. `X$id = paste0("ID-",X$id)` will ad "ID-" as a prefix.